# Group by and add or subtract depending on the indicator

Tags: powershell

I have a file which has transaction_date, transaction_amount and debit_credit_indicator. I want to write a program which shows for each date total count and total amount.

Total amount is calculated as follows -

if debit_credit_indicator is 'C' add else if 'D' subtract.

I got till grouping by indicators but don't know how to proceed after wards.

My ouput looks like this

```
TRANSACTION_DATE    DEBIT_CREDIT_INDICA         TotalAmount Count              
                    TOR                                                        
----------------    -------------------         ----------- -----              
2019-02-26          C                                  1478                    
2019-02-25          D                                   100                    
2019-02-26          D                                   200
```

```
param([string]$inputFileName=30)


(Get-Content $inputFileName) -replace '\|', ',' | Set-Content c:\learnpowershell\test.csv


$transactionData = Import-csv c:\learnpowershell\test.csv | Group-Object -Property TRANSACTION_DATE, DEBIT_CREDIT_INDICATOR 

[Array] $newsbData += foreach($gitem in $transactionData)
{
$gitem.group | Select -Unique TRANSACTION_DATE, DEBIT_CREDIT_INDICATOR,  `
@{Name = ‘TotalAmount’;Expression = {(($gitem.group) | measure -Property TRANSACTION_AMOUNT -sum).sum}},
@{Name = ‘Count’;Expression = {(($gitem.group) | Measure-Object -count).count}}
};



write-output $newsbData
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want replace '|' by ',' because you dont know -delimiter option otherwise keep you code for replace. now i propose my code for your problem:

```
#import en group by date
import-csv "c:\learnpowershell\test.csv" -Delimiter '|' | group TRANSACTION_DATE | %{
$TotalCredit=0
$TotalDebit=0
$CountRowCredit=0
$CountRowDebit=0
$HasProblem=$false

#calculation by date for every group

$_.Group | %{
                if ($_.DEBIT_CREDIT_INDICATOR -EQ 'C')
                {
                   $TotalCredit+=$_.transaction_amount
                   $CountRowCredit++ 
                }
                elseif ($_.DEBIT_CREDIT_INDICATOR -EQ 'D')
                {
                   $TotalDebit+=$_.transaction_amount 
                   $CountRowDebit++
                }
                else
                {
                   $HasProblem=$true
                }
}

#output result
[pscustomobject]@{
TRANSACTION_DATE=$_.Name
CountRow=$_.Count
Credit_Total=$TotalCredit
Credit_CountRow=$CountRowCredit
Debit_Total=-$TotalDebit
Debit_CountRow=$CountRowDebit
Total_DebitCredit=$TotalCredit - $TotalDebit
HasProblem=$HasProblem
}


}
```

You can add ' | Format-Table ' if you want print result formated in table

Comment: Perfect. You rock. Thank you so much